# IF user type = 1 then select form table 1 else select form table 2

Tags: mysql, if-statement, multiple-tables

i need a mysql query that can query the result like 
if user type =1 then select form table one else select form table 2 
please help me to build this query

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer 
here is the solution

SELECT IF(UserType = 1,(select Name from Users where UserID = 1),(select Name from Admin where AdminID = 1)) FROM Messages